# See the data entered in the count calculation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

For example I have data like this :

| CustomerID | Trans_date |
| --- | --- |
| C001 | 01-sep-22 |
| C001 | 04-sep-22 |
| C001 | 14-sep-22 |
| C002 | 03-sep-22 |
| C002 | 01-sep-22 |
| C002 | 18-sep-22 |
| C002 | 20-sep-22 |
| C003 | 02-sep-22 |
| C003 | 28-sep-22 |
| C004 | 08-sep-22 |
| C004 | 18-sep-22 |

If I want to see who is coming between August 29, 2022 to September 4, 2022 and they will return between September 5, 2022 to September 11, 2022, then I will use this code:

```
select count(distinct CustomerID) 
from trydata
where CustTrans between '2022-09-01' and '2022-09-04'
  and CustomerID in (select distinct CustomerID 
                     from trydata
                     where CustTrans between '2022-09-12' and '2022-09-18')
```

The results returned will show the number of people to be 2. But from the results I don't know who it is, how can I display who the 2 people are from the results of the code above? Thanks

Comment: Remove the COUNT().

Comment: so its start with select * from trydata where..... ?

Comment: No, I said *remove the COUNT()*, not *remove the COUNT(distinct CustomerID)*. It would be `SELECT distinct CustomerID` and the rest of the query.